# Rails get all objects through a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**User** has_many **Questions**

**Question** belongs_to **User**

How can I get all **users** for **questions** that have their "tag" column equal to "ruby-on-rails"?

If I do `Question.where(tag: "ruby-on-rails")`, I get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

If I do `Question.where(tag: "ruby-on-rails").users` I get an error `undefined method 'users' for #<Question::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbb96812aa0>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
User.joins(:questions).where(questions: {tag: "ruby-on-rails"})
```